# Apply model changes immediately

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've form with some input fields, upon submit I make a $http call and populate a model object that binds data to a table on my view. Once user saw the result, they may change the data in the form and submit the same once again, I'm trying to clear the result and populate the data with the new result. Some time the result can be same, in such cases user is not able to understand whether the form was submitted and new results has been updated or not. I'm setting my model object to undefined expecting that the data on the table will get wiped. I also have an ng-if for null check of the object and control the display of the table, I expect it to hide the table, but unfortunately it is not happening. How can I do that? $scope.apply() is the only way for me to do that. I hate to use it as it causes full digest cycle. Please advise.

Comment: show us some code. What is the problem and what you have done so far??

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate scope for clearing the data and call that using model on button click.

Example

```
    $scope.clearData = function () {
        $scope.ApplicationFormName = "";
        $scope.FirstName="";
           //put your logic for clearing the form here

    };

in HTML

       <button title="Clear" ng-click="clearData()"></button>
```